# Is it possible to check if an event's callback is in use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

Given node's event emitter, I want to return a boolean of whether the event has an `.on(...)` callback in use or not.

```js
function eventHasDotOnCallback(eventName) {
   // const isInUse = <Code>
   return isInUse;
}

EventEmitter.emit('event1');
EventEmitter.emit('event2');

EventEmitter.on('event2', () => {
   console.log('This callback is in use!');
});

console.log(eventHasDotOnCallback('event1'));
// false

console.log(eventHasDotOnCallback('event2'));
// true
```

How is this possible, if at all?

Comment: In general, it’s probably possible using a [Proxy](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `emitter.rawListeners('event1')` will give you a raw list of listeners for the event `event1`.  If it returns an empty array, then there are no listeners for that event name.

For example, here's a function that you pass an emitter and an eventName and it tells you if there are any listeners for that eventName:

```
function hasListener(emitter, eventName) {
    const listeners = emitter.rawListeners(eventName);
    return listeners && listeners.length;
}
```

`emitter.listeners('event1')` is similar.  My understanding of the difference is that `.rawListeners()` will also include wrapped listeners that are added with `.once()` instead of `.on()`.

And, `emitter.eventNames()` will gives you an array of event names that there are any listeners for.

If you control the creation of the `eventEmitter` object, you could also either proxy several methods or monkey patch several methods in order to "watch" what listeners are added to the `eventEmitter` object, though it's probably easier to just use the `.rawListeners()` method later to see what is or isn't listening for any given event name.